# How can I add a "magik" command, discord js

Tags: discord.js

I was looking for how to create that command that distorts the images, but I can't find anything, how can I do it? I use discord js

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a "majik" command (that distorts an avatar for example), you will need to use a library like [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) or [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas).
If you want something more quick and easy, I can recommend the package [discord.js-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-canvas), it has a distort function.